# OpenFileDialog is blocked by Norton Antivirus if project was generated by SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, antivirus, sharpdevelop

If you create a new winform project with SharpDevelop 4, then drag an OpenFileDialog (or SaveFileDialog) to the form, then show the dialog (.ShowDialog), Norton internet security 2011 blocks the application and delete it (the binary). The sonar protection of norton reports a "suspicious behaving" of the application.
This does not happens with projects created by Visual Studio. I run Win 7.

I thought maybe this have something to do with a lack of single-threaded apartment attribute. Does SharpDevelop use this attribute for winforms? Where it is located? And in general: What difference between SharpDevelop and Visual Studio's Auto-generated code may cause this?

EDIT:

- The problem occurs both inside SharpDevelop debugging and outside with the binary.
- Setting .AutoUpgradeEnabled to False solved the problem. However, when code generated by Visual Studio,
  the problem doesn't occur regardless of the value of .AutoUpgradeEnabled.

Comment: I would classify this as a bug with Norton, have you reported it?

Comment: Does this happen while debugging from inside SharpDevelop or while running stand-alone?

Comment: Is the value of the AutoUpgradeEnabled property on the dialog the same?  If not then there's an explanation.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks to your comment the problem have been solved (see edited question). But what is the explanation?

Comment: You need to take control back on that machine.  Either lose the cr*ppy malware scanner or uninstall the cr*ppy shell extension that causes the problem.  Ask at superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

IF the issue does not occur with norton turned off, it's an issue for SharpDevelop 4 to contact norton and register the .dll's and file signatures so that norton will not flag the component as harmful. Not really a .net issue. I would contact the vendor of SharpDevelop 4.